# Como hacer multiples peticiones y gestionarlas en un solo oyente - Android Volley

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

Tengo una clase que trata sobre recuperar contraseña, esta clase hace 2 consultas al web service, la primera obtiene los datos del usuario automaticamente (no hace falta interversion del usuario) a partir del correo electronico y la segunda consulta se da cuando el usuario presiona el boton Enviar codigo (lo que hace este boton es solicitar al web service que le envie un codigo de seguridad a su correo para autorizar el reestablecimiento de su contraseña del usuario), mi problema esque en mi clase yo tengo implementada el `Response.Listener<String>, Response.ErrorListener` y eso automaticamente me genera los metodos de:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
}
```

ahora cuando hago mis dos consultas las respuesta de ambas entran por ese dos metodos (onResponse, onErrorResponse), como puedo saber cual respuesta pertenece a cual solicitud? se puede agregar algun tipo de `id` o `tag` a las peticiones para asi poder identificar de quien es la respuesta?. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente recuerda que la respuesta a tu petición siempre se obtendrá en en el método `onResponse()` en la variable `response`

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
}
```

Pero si estas obteniendo una respuesta en el método `onErrorResponse()` , esto indica que se obtuvo un error en la petición!

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
}
```

En realidad no debería llamarse este callback ya que indica que existe algún problema.

---

**Para identificar cada petición `Volley` puedes precisamente definir un tag** (Etiqueta a tu petición).

Para esto define una interfaz:

```
public interface VolleyResponse {

void onResponse(JSONObject object, String tag);

void onError(VolleyError error, String tag);

}
```

Y crea un handler personalizado para las peticiones:

```
public class CustomRequest implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {

private VolleyResponse volleyResponse;
private String tag;
private JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;


public CustomRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonObject, String tag, VolleyResponse volleyResponse) {
    this.volleyResponse = volleyResponse;
    this.tag= tag;
    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url, jsonObject, this, this);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    volleyResponse.onResponse(response, tag);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    volleyResponse.onError(error, tag);
}

public JsonObjectRequest getJsonObjectRequest() {
    return jsonObjectRequest;
}
}
```

Ahora para usar la clase anterior debes implementar en tu clase, la clase `VolleyResponse`, lo cual provocará que sobrescribas los métodos `onResponse()` y `onErrorResponse()`, ejemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VolleyResponse {

 ...
 ...   
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONObject object, String tag) {
       Log.i("Response :", object.toString() + "   " + tag);
  }

  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error,  String tag) {

  }      

 }
```

Por ùltimo, la forma de llamar las peticiones definiendo un tag, se realizaría de esta forma, ejemplo:

```
CustomRequest request1 = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new JSONObject(), "Request 1", this);


CustomRequest request2 = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new JSONObject(), "Request 2", this);
```

Revisa esta pregunta en el sitio en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158362/get-volley-request-tag-in-response